# libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: package-management, graphics, shared-library

I'm trying to install libglut.so.3 that is required by an application.
I have installed freeglut3, freeglut3-dev, but again same error as the title of this question.

I have searched then with a `sudo apt search glut` and nothing new is coming out.

Doing a `sudo find / -type f | grep libglut.so.3` I can see this:

```
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
```

Now, even if I have installed freeglut3 and the -dev one, still get same error.

I'm thinking now to try to link in some way the libglut.so.3.9.o that I see under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ but don't know how to do it or if it works.

Why I still get error `libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` ?
How can I fix this?
Where are located all shared libraries that is looking for?

Thanks so much, this is becoming a pain in the neck since weeks now, so I decided to write to all of you.

My system is a 32bit i5 4GB ram

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

---

Again same problem with libcv.so.4 now.
Installed libcv, libcvaux, -dev, :i386 doesn't work.

Can't find version 4 of libcv, only 2.4.

How do I know where to pick the libraries from?
just doing apt search doesn't help very much.

A find outputs this:

```
sudo find / -type f | grep libcv
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcv2.4.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcvaux-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcv2.4.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcv-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcv-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcvaux-dev:amd64.list
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libcvdsub_plugin.so
/usr/share/doc/libcv2.4/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libcvaux-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libcv-dev/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcv2.4
```

Thinking about some symbolic link to /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcv2.4?

Answer (score 22):

You need to install one package:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3
```

It will install libraries to */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3* and */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0*.

If it does not help try to find shared object dependencies of your `application` with
`ldd application` to find its dependencies.
And check `application` arch (32- or 64-bit) with `file application`.

If it is 32-bit you should install 32-bit freeglut with:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3:i386 freeglut3-dev:i386
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! It was the damn architecture, with :i386 I solved the problem! Idiot me :)